# python manage.py migrate does not create a table

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, migrate

I use postgresql and my python version is 3.7
I have tried all the commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

This creates a file in migrations named 0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.10 on 2020-02-17 12:01
```

from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Support',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
            ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
            ('message', models.TextField()),
        ],
    ),
]
```

now when I pass the command to migrate,

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It shows that 'No migrations to apply'

```
    (myvenv) C:\nid\project>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, scholarship, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

This is my **models.py** class:

```
    from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.


class Support(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I know that this question has been asked before. I checked them all but no answer is able to solve this problem. Please help

Comment: In which app the model `Support` belongs?

Answer (score 6):

Bit of an old post but I just encountered the same issue and was able to fix it by simply running:
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Answer (score 0):

In general, this means that the table already exists in your DB.
I suggest that you try to delete your table and then recreate it with `py manage.py migrate`.

Reply if you have further problems

Comment: I deleted the entry from django_migrations table and tried it again and now it works fine

Comment: Perfect. You could add your solution as answer for other users with the same problem

Comment: As a side note: if reason was that the table already existed prior to running the migration, the result would be a db error (trying to create a table that already exists), not a "no migration to apply" message. The OP did the right thing here (nb: for this very special case I mean): removing the entry from the migrations history table.

Answer (score 0):

So what happens behind the scenes is:

When you run the command:
`python manage.py makemigrations`

A migration file gets created based on your model or model changes.

When you run:
`python manage.py migrate`

Django uses the newly created file inside the migrations folders and performs the actions accordingly AND a corresponding entry is created in the table `django_migrations` (sort of a log).

Now even if you DELETE the table from DB and the migration file from the folder, the migrate command will not work because the new file created will always be named '0001_initial.py' as you have deleted the previous migration file.

If you explore the table 'django_migrations' you will find a entry with your app_name and migrations file name. Example:

myApp 0001_initial

Django will always assume that the migration has already run before and will not run it again.

***How to fix?***

**Option 1:**
`python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

**Option 2:**
Delete the particular entry that's conflicting with your last migration filename / or the one you want to run / or all of them related to that app